# Boot Loop Philips 55PFS8153 - UART Logfile

Tags: boot

My TV is stuck in a boot loop.The classic tips don't help, I can't get into the Recovery Menu or the Service Alignment Mode. I connected it to the service interface and this is what I got:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
[11.912805] TZ CPU0 ERROR[tz_sw_verify_image:75] verify image fail, src=0x19c00000, len=0x02738c00, dst=0x19c00000GIH magic num is not correct (0x482a4d49 != 0x00010080)!!!
recovery partition image is not proper !!!
****** BOOTLOADER_NORMAL_RESET_STAGE********
Send WARMUP_1_RESP.
Answering WU_FROM_DDR_OFF1.
[  694618]I(SM): SM:Enter warmup state
[  694622]I(SM): ******leave flow ---Sysreset to FastActive---
Send FAST RESET command to SM
[  694821]W(SM): %%%%SM:Msg FAST SYSTEM RESET%%%%
[  694825]I(SM): ******enter flow ---Sysreset to FastActive---
[  694832]I(SM): peripheral_assert done
[  694835]I(SM): soc_assert done
[  694838]I(SM): mv_sm_power_socpoweroff done
[  695143]I(SM): mv_sm_power_socpoweron done
[  695203]I(SM): peripheral_assert done
[  695207]I(SM): soc_assert done
[  695303]I(SM): peripheral_deassert done
[  695306]W(SM): ### Wake Up Reason 0x0[  695310]I(SM): soc_deassert done
[  695313]E(SM): mv_sm_timer_start - arg check fail!
/_S?àḞb[     0] sys_init start. boot_strap=0x00000514 (source=eMMC), boot_state=0x7
image verify fail!!!
remote:ea84e1950f9bbe56d176bbfa1ae646ae5750a3cabda467c4b16bc4939c57926e
local :
tzk image verify fail.
[   415] image verified, start at 0x00920000...
tz kernel starting... MV88DE3114(BG2Q)-A1 total 4 cpus, v2.0.0.21, Aug  5 2014 14:39:52
0213[   471] start_bootloader
UẂULAUNCH_ITM is set to zero
board_number = 2
uiBoot = 7
I2C switch set as 0
I2C switch set as 1
--------- I2C Initialization ----------
I2C_INIT: I2C-2 bus
I2C_INIT: I2C-1 bus
I2C_INIT: I2C-0 bus
DDR reg 0xF7CB0BAC value : 0x00021421
DDR reg 0xF7CB0C00 value : 0x00004031
leakage info 400.
set Vcpu to 1300mV, default setting by hardware.
core from 1200 to 1150
set Vcore to 1175mv
set Vcore to 1150mv
set Vcore to 1150 mv.
SPLASH: wakeup_reason : 0
****** SPLASH ENABLED FOR Recovery********
flash_ts_init() success.
RDKDMP BG2Q [Oct 27 2017 18:04:12]
Pinmux configuration:
GSM 0xf7fcd040 0x009c0261;
0xf7ea0014: 00000072 00240611 00000253 1249008a
0xf7ea0028: 01249492 00000048 1ca54009 0430e44d
0xf7ea003c: 00000000 00000000 0000001f 63c06a5
Clock configuration:
 VCO_B      frequency 1620
 AVPLLB[4]  frequency 300
 AVPLLB[5]  frequency 800
 AVPLLB[6]  frequency 1680
 AVPLLB[7]  frequency 610
 cpuPll     frequency 1200
 memPll     frequency 1500
 sysPll     frequency 800
 dClk       frequency 375
 cpuClk     frequency 1200
 sysClk     frequency 400
 drmClk     frequency 400
 cfgClk     frequency 100
 gfxClk     frequency 400
 zspClk     frequency 400
 perifClk   frequency 200
 pCubeClk   frequency 610
 vScopeClk  frequency 610
 nfcEccClk  frequency 100
 vppSysClk  frequency 400
 appClk     frequency 800
 gfx3DCoreClk   frequency 420
 gfx3DSysClk    frequency 400
 arcRefClk  frequency 400
 vipClk     frequency 400
 sdioXinClk frequency 200
 sdio1XinClk    frequency 200
 gfx3DShClk frequency 420
 avif0Clk   frequency 300
 avif1Clk   frequency 300
[00,sd00] bootloader: part1(start=0, blks=1, version=201710271804), part2(start=0, blks=1, version=000000000000)
[01,sd01] fts: part1(start=32, blks=32, version=201710271804), part2(start=32, blks=32, version=000000000000)
[02,sd02] recovery: part1(start=64, blks=120, version=201710271804), part2(start=64, blks=120, version=000000000000)
[03,sd03] tzk_recovery: part1(start=184, blks=8, version=201710271804), part2(start=184, blks=8, version=000000000000)
[04,sd04] factory_setting: part1(start=192, blks=128, version=201710271804), part2(start=192, blks=128, version=000000000000)
[05,sd05] itm: part1(start=320, blks=128, version=201710271804), part2(start=320, blks=128, version=000000000000)
[06,sd06] boot: part1(start=448, blks=24, version=201710271804), part2(start=448, blks=24, version=000000000000)
[07,sd07] tzk_normal: part1(start=472, blks=8, version=201710271804), part2(start=472, blks=8, version=000000000000)
[08,sd08] system: part1(start=480, blks=1600, version=201710271804), part2(start=480, blks=1600, version=000000000000)
[09,sd09] user_setting: part1(start=2080, blks=960, version=201710271804), part2(start=2080, blks=960, version=000000000000)
[10,sd10] cache: part1(start=3040, blks=896, version=201710271804), part2(start=3040, blks=896, version=000000000000)
[11,sd11] firmware: part1(start=3936, blks=64, version=201710271804), part2(start=3936, blks=64, version=000000000000)
[12,sd12] factory_data: part1(start=4000, blks=32, version=201710271804), part2(start=4000, blks=32, version=000000000000)
[13,sd13] userdata: part1(start=4032, blks=3328, version=201710271804), part2(start=4032, blks=3328, version=000000000000)
get macaddr from fts: 1c:5a:6b:XXXXXX
macaddr=1c:5a:6b:XXXXXXX
get_reset_msg,1262: sysreset, need to get reset_msg_extra_size=0
tzk boot with recovery mode
--> Theen reboot again and again
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? According to the service manual you can also flash the firmware via the service port, but no idea how.

I am grateful for every tip.